# Building wheel for udatetime (setup.py) error / failed building wheel - WINDOWS

Tags: python, pip, windows-10

I am a beginner with using Python/command line. However, I've successfully been able to install/use Python and install packages using pip via Windows Powershell. Recently I've been attempting to install 'udatetime' and I can't figure out why it continues to error out and fail to install.

**Here is some information about my setup and this problem:**

- OS: Windows 10
- Python Version: 3.8.2

**Previously Attempted Solutions**

- Installed Microsoft Visual Studio C++
- Installed wheels package
- Upgrade pip / setuptools

**Error Code (via Command Line)**

```
Collecting udatetime
  Using cached udatetime-0.0.16.tar.gz (13 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: udatetime
  Building wheel for udatetime (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\Bpkennedy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Bpkennedy\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-irfu9reg\\udatetime\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Bpkennedy\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-irfu9reg\\udatetime\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\Bpkennedy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-ifmu4a0c'
       cwd: C:\Users\Bpkennedy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-irfu9reg\udatetime\
  Complete output (34 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\udatetime
  copying udatetime\_pure.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\udatetime
  copying udatetime\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\udatetime
  running egg_info
  writing udatetime.egg-info\PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to udatetime.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
  writing top-level names to udatetime.egg-info\top_level.txt
  reading manifest file 'udatetime.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  writing manifest file 'udatetime.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  running build_ext
  building 'udatetime.rfc3339' extension
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\src
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -D_PYTHON3=1 -IC:\Users\Bpkennedy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\include -IC:\Users\Bpkennedy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tc./src/rfc3339.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\./src/rfc3339.obj -Ofast -std=c99
  cl : Command line warning D9025 : overriding '/Os' with '/Ot'
  cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-Of'
  cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-Oa'
  cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-std=c99'
  rfc3339.c
  ./src/rfc3339.c(100): error C2079: 't' uses undefined struct 'timeb'
  ./src/rfc3339.c(101): warning C4013: 'ftime' undefined; assuming extern returning int
  ./src/rfc3339.c(102): error C2224: left of '.time' must have struct/union type
  ./src/rfc3339.c(102): error C2224: left of '.millitm' must have struct/union type
  ./src/rfc3339.c(102): warning C4033: '_gettime' must return a value
  ./src/rfc3339.c(275): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'size_t' to 'double', possible loss of data
  ./src/rfc3339.c(275): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'double' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.27.29110\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for udatetime
  Running setup.py clean for udatetime
Failed to build udatetime
DEPRECATION: Could not build wheels for udatetime which do not use PEP 517. pip will fall back to legacy 'setup.py install' for these. pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality. A possible replacement is to fix the wheel build issue reported above. You can find discussion regarding this at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8368.
Installing collected packages: udatetime
    Running setup.py install for udatetime ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\Bpkennedy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Bpkennedy\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-irfu9reg\\udatetime\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Bpkennedy\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-irfu9reg\\udatetime\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Bpkennedy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-_iw6ed71\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Bpkennedy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Include\udatetime'
         cwd: C:\Users\Bpkennedy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-irfu9reg\udatetime\
    Complete output (34 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\udatetime
    copying udatetime\_pure.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\udatetime
    copying udatetime\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\udatetime
    running egg_info
    writing udatetime.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to udatetime.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to udatetime.egg-info\top_level.txt
    reading manifest file 'udatetime.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    writing manifest file 'udatetime.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    running build_ext
    building 'udatetime.rfc3339' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\src
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -D_PYTHON3=1 -IC:\Users\Bpkennedy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\include -IC:\Users\Bpkennedy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tc./src/rfc3339.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\./src/rfc3339.obj -Ofast -std=c99
    cl : Command line warning D9025 : overriding '/Os' with '/Ot'
    cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-Of'
    cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-Oa'
    cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-std=c99'
    rfc3339.c
    ./src/rfc3339.c(100): error C2079: 't' uses undefined struct 'timeb'
    ./src/rfc3339.c(101): warning C4013: 'ftime' undefined; assuming extern returning int
    ./src/rfc3339.c(102): error C2224: left of '.time' must have struct/union type
    ./src/rfc3339.c(102): error C2224: left of '.millitm' must have struct/union type
    ./src/rfc3339.c(102): warning C4033: '_gettime' must return a value
    ./src/rfc3339.c(275): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'size_t' to 'double', possible loss of data
    ./src/rfc3339.c(275): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'double' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.27.29110\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\Bpkennedy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Bpkennedy\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-irfu9reg\\udatetime\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Bpkennedy\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-irfu9reg\\udatetime\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Bpkennedy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-_iw6ed71\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Bpkennedy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Include\udatetime' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Thank you for anyone who can help me with this. It's driving me a little crazy and I've read many other Stack Overflow posts to try to resolve with no success.

Bryan

Answer (score 1):

[`udatetime` version 0.0.16](https://pypi.org/project/udatetime/0.0.16/), latest release was at Feb 14, 2018. Supports Python **2.6**, 2.7 and 3.5 (I really doubt it supports Python 3).

Seems like an outdated abandoned Python2-only project. My advice: forget it and move on.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up not using udatetime and therefore, no longer needed to resolve this problem.